# Evaluating $\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} x \sin(2\pi x/L) \cos(\pi x/L) \,dx$, knowing $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} x \sin(2\pi x) \cos(\pi x) \,dx$

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

If I have this result:
$$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} x \sin(2\pi x) \cos(\pi x) \,dx=\frac{8}{9 \pi^2} $$ and I have to solve this integral:
$$\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} x \sin(2\pi x/L) \cos(\pi x/L) \,dx$$
How do I solve it?

Comment: **Hint:** Integration by substitution.

Comment: Let $t=\frac{x}{L}$ then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint in the comments, you can use a change of variable and let $u=x/L$ such that $du=dx/L$. Then, $x\in[-L/2,L/2]$ implies that $u\in[-1/2,1/2]$ so when you rewrite your integral in terms of $u$, you get $$L^2\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} u\sin(2\pi u)\cos(\pi u)\,du,$$ which you should recognise from here :)